# How to add to card without login, without user authentication. Help in session method of Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, e-commerce

How to add to card without login, without user authentication. Help in session method of Django.

I am stuck in this. How to modify this code, so I can easily implement add to card, add to wishlist without login and also connected with users.

Models.py

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_qty = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 
class Wishlist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

wishlist.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from buyjoi.models import Product, Cart, Wishlist
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='loginpage')
def wishlistpage(request):
    wishlistitem = Wishlist.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = {'wishlistitem':wishlistitem}
    return render(request, 'wishlist.html', context)

def addtowishlist(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            prod_id = int(request.POST.get('product_id'))
            product_check = Product.objects.get(id=prod_id)
            if(product_check):
                if(Wishlist.objects.filter(user=request.user, product_id=prod_id)):
                    return JsonResponse({'status':"Product already in wishlist"})
                else:
                    Wishlist.objects.create(user=request.user, product_id=prod_id)
                    return JsonResponse({'status':"Product added to wishlist"})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'status':"No such product found"})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status':"Login to continue"})
    return redirect('/')


def deletewishlistitem(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            prod_id = int(request.POST.get('product_id'))
            
            if(Wishlist.objects.filter(user=request.user, product_id=prod_id)):
                wishlistitem = Wishlist.objects.get(product_id=prod_id)
                wishlistitem.delete()
                return JsonResponse({'status':"Product removed from wishlist"})
            else:
                Wishlist.objects.create(user=request.user, product_id=prod_id)
                return JsonResponse({'status':"Product not found in wishlist"})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status':"Login to continue"})

    return redirect('/')
```

checkout.py

```
from http.client import HTTPResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from buyjoi.models import Product, Cart, Order, OrderItem, Profile, EmailSubcription
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import random
from django.http import JsonResponse

@login_required(login_url='loginpage')
def checkoutpage(request):
    rawcart = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    for item in rawcart:
        if item.product_qty > item.product.quantity:
            Cart.objects.delete(id=item.id)

        cartitems = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        total_price = 0
        for item in cartitems:
            total_price = total_price + item.product.selling_price * item.product_qty
            
        userprofile = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()

        context = {'cartitems': cartitems, 'total_price':total_price, 'userprofile':userprofile}
        return render(request, "checkout.html", context)
    
    
@login_required(login_url='loginpage')
def placeorder(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        currentuser = User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).first()
        
        if not currentuser.first_name :
            currentuser.first_name = request.POST.get('fname')
            currentuser.last_name = request.POST.get('lname')
            currentuser.save()
        
        if not Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user):
            userprofile = Profile()
            userprofile.user = request.user
            userprofile.phone = request.POST.get('phone')
            userprofile.pincode = request.POST.get('pincode')
            userprofile.flat = request.POST.get('flat')
            userprofile.area = request.POST.get('area')
            userprofile.landmark = request.POST.get('landmark')
            userprofile.city = request.POST.get('city')
            userprofile.state = request.POST.get('state')
            userprofile.save()
            
        neworder = Order()
        neworder.user = request.user
        neworder.fname = request.POST.get('fname')
        neworder.lname = request.POST.get('lname')
        neworder.phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        neworder.pincode = request.POST.get('pincode')
        neworder.flat = request.POST.get('flat')
        neworder.area = request.POST.get('area')
        neworder.landmark = request.POST.get('landmark')
        neworder.city = request.POST.get('city')
        neworder.state = request.POST.get('state')        
        neworder.payment_mode = request.POST.get('payment_mode')
        neworder.payment_id = request.POST.get('payment_id')
        
        cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        cart_total_price = 0
        for item in cart:
            cart_total_price = cart_total_price + item.product.selling_price * item.product_qty            
            
        neworder.total_price = cart_total_price
        trackno = 'buyjoi'+str(random.randint(1111111,9999999))   
        while Order.objects.filter(tracking_no=trackno) is None:
            trackno = 'buyjoi'+str(random.randint(1111111,9999999))

        neworder.tracking_no = trackno
        neworder.save()

        neworderitems = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        for item in neworderitems:
            OrderItem.objects.create(
                order=neworder,
                product=item.product,
                price=item.product.selling_price,
                quantity=item.product_qty

            )
            
            # to decrease product quantity from available stock
            
            orderproduct = Product.objects.filter(id=item.product_id).first()
            orderproduct.quantity = orderproduct.quantity - item.product_qty
            orderproduct.save()

        # to make clear the cart
        Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user).delete()
        
        messages.success(request, "Your order has been placed successfuly!")
        
        payMode = request.POST.get('payment_mode')
        if (payMode == "Paid by Razorpay"):
            return JsonResponse({'status':"Your order has been placed successfuly!"})
                
    return redirect('/')

@login_required(login_url='loginpage')
def proceedtopay(request):
    cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    total_price = 0
    for item in cart:
        total_price = total_price + item.product.selling_price * item.product_qty
    return JsonResponse({
        'total_price' : total_price
    })
    
def footer(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        emailhome = request.POST.get['email']
        data = EmailSubcription( emailtosubscribe=emailhome )
        data.save()
    return render(request, 'footer.html')
```

cart.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from buyjoi.models import Product, Cart
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def addtocart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            prod_id = int(request.POST.get('product_id'))
            product_check = Product.objects.get(id=prod_id)

            if (product_check):
                if (Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, product_id=prod_id)):
                    return JsonResponse({'status': "Product Already in Cart"})
                else:
                    prod_qty = int(request.POST.get('product_qty'))

                    if product_check.quantity >= prod_qty:
                        Cart.objects.create(
                            user=request.user, product_id=prod_id, product_qty=prod_qty)
                        return JsonResponse({'status': "Product added successfully"})
                    else:
                        return JsonResponse({'status': "Only " + str(product_check.quantity) + " quantity available"})

            else:
                return JsonResponse({'status': "No such product found"})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status': "Login to Continue"})

    return redirect("/")


@login_required(login_url='loginpage')
def viewcart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        context = {
            'cart': cart
        }
        return render(request, "cart.html", context)
    else:
        messages.error(
            request, "Kindly login to access this section, Thank you.")
        return redirect("/")


def updatecart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        prod_id = int(request.POST.get('product_id'))
        if (Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user, product_id=prod_id)):
            prod_qty = int(request.POST.get('product_qty'))
            cart = Cart.objects.get(product_id=prod_id, user=request.user)
            cart.product_qty = prod_qty
            cart.save()
            return JsonResponse({'status': "Updated Successfully"})
    return redirect('/')


def deletecartitem(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        prod_id = int(request.POST.get('product_id'))
        if(Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user, product_id=prod_id)):
            cartitem = Cart.objects.get(product_id=prod_id, user=request.user)
            cartitem.delete()
        return JsonResponse({'status:"Deleted Successfully"'})
    return redirect('/')
```

cartcode.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.addToCartBtn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var product_id = $(this).closest('.product_data').find('.prod_id').val();
    var product_qty = $(this).closest('.product_data').find('.qty_input').val();
    var token = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/add-to-cart",
      data: {
        'product_id': product_id,
        'product_qty': product_qty,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: token,
      },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        alertify.success(response.status);
      },
    });
  });


  $('.addToWishlist').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var product_id = $(this).closest('.product_data').find('.prod_id').val();
    var token = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/add-to-wishlist",
      data: {
        'product_id': product_id,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: token,
      },
      success: function (response) {
        alertify.success(response.status);
      },
    });
  });


  $('.changeQuantity').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var product_id = $(this).closest('.product_data').find('.prod_id').val();
    var product_qty = $(this).closest('.product_data').find('.qty_input').val();
    var token = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/update-cart",
      data: {
        'product_id': product_id,
        'product_qty': product_qty,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: token,
      },
      success: function (response) {
      },
    });
  });

  $('.deletecartitemBtn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var product_id = $(this).closest('.product_data').find('.prod_id').val();
    var token = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
    
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/delete-cart-item",
      data: {
        'product_id': product_id,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: token,
      },
      success: function (response) {
        alertify.success(response.status)

      },
    });
  });
  
  $('.deletewishlistbtn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var product_id = $(this).closest('.product_data').find('.prod_id').val();
    var token = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
    
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/delete-wishlist-item",
      data: {
        'product_id': product_id,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: token,
      },
      success: function (response) {
        alertify.success(response.status)

      },
    });
  });
});
```